# error of importing DBI in Perl

Tags: perl, dbi

I am writing the code in Perl and try to save it in the extension `.pm` not `.pl`

and I use `use DBI;` to import the DBI in order that I can execute the query.

and the error is `compilation failed in require`.

However, I did use in `script.pl` , it s okay.. it works..

Please help and thank you very much

Comment: please show the full line that the error is reported on and the exact full error message.

Comment: I suspect it's "Compilation" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably simply miss the "1;" at the end of the .pm file.

Perl modules always have to return a "true" value. This is accomplished by simply putting "1;" at the end of the file.

More information can be found in the example code of [Perl Modules](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.12.3/pod/perlmod.pod#Perl_Modules_) in the perlmod documentation.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but according to perldiag the error that occurs in that case is "<module> did not return a true value".

Answer (score 1):

"Compilation failed in require" indicates compilation cannot continue beyond that point due to an *earlier* error. Solve the earlier error and this one will go away.