# Problem of import DBI module - Compilation failed in require

Tags: perl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [error of importing DBI in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036430/error-of-importing-dbi-in-perl)

I have a problem when I use the DBI module in another module, `script.pm`.

```
package CC;


use DBI;
use strict; 
use Alias;


my $dbFile = 'XXXXXXXX.db';

my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:$dbFile","","",
    {RaiseError =>1, AutoCommit => 1})or "Unable to connect:  $DBI::errstr\n";


use Alias qw(attr);
our ($CURRENTOFFSET,@LANGUAGE);

sub new {
    my $that = shift;
    my $class = ref($that)|| $that;
    my $self = {
        CURRENTOFFSET=> undef,
        LANGUAGE => []  
    };
    bless($self, $class);
    return $self;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Do you have an error message?

Comment: This is an expanded version of yesterday's question - it is better than yesterday's question because it includes some code to critique, but doesn't have a good explanation of what the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Substantive

Conventionally, a package `XYZ` is kept in a file `XYZ.pm`; Perl won't find your package otherwise.  Thus, your file should be `CC.pm` rather than `script.pm`.

Note that a package `Organization::Team::Purpose` is kept in a file `Purpose.pm`, but the file is kept in a sub-directory `Organization/Team` and the base directory holding `Organization` has to be found by Perl (using `-I/some/where` if `Organization` is a sub-directory of the directory `/some/where`, for example; if it is a sub-directory of the current directory, it will be found anyway).

You should probably review the `or` clause after your connection attempt.  Normally, you do a `die` or `croak` there.  You simply evaluate a string, which is not very useful.

You have:

```
my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:$dbFile","","",
    {RaiseError =>1, AutoCommit => 1})or "Unable to connect:  $DBI::errstr\n";
```

You should consider what to do, but one technique is:

```
use Carp;
my $db = DBI->connect("dbi:SQLite:$dbFile", "", "",
                      { RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 })
         or croak "Unable to connect: $DBI::errstr\n";
```

The downside of that is that this is going into a module, and it isn't necessarily a good idea to croak in the BEGIN code of a module (and I'm making an assumption that the code is executed as the module is loaded).  You might need to store the `undef` database handle and protect other methods from using it.  You might be better off deferring the 'connect to database' operation until the constructor `new` is used (possibly for the first time).  It is at least legitimate to raise errors at that point.

As the answer by [DVK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119280/dvk) noted (before I wrote my answer), modules should end with `1;` to indicate successful loading.  Maybe you can exploit that to report an error on failure to load - the final condition might be '`defined $db ? 0 : 1;`' (or even just '`defined $db;`'), but it would be crucial to generate an error message somehow to explain the problem.

#### Trivia

You should be ruthlessly consistent in the spacing around operators, too.  Your example includes:

```
{RaiseError =>1, AutoCommit => 1}
my $class = ref($that)|| $that;
CURRENTOFFSET=> undef,
```

which would be better written as:

```
{RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1}
my $class = ref($that) || $that;
CURRENTOFFSET => undef,
```

The first might benefit from a little more space:

```
{ RaiseError => 1, AutoCommit => 1 }
```

It doesn't directly affect the operation of the code.  It does make it a little less easy to read.  Learning to be consistent is an important part of learning to program.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the fact that this is a package, and your code sample doesn't end with "`1;`", try adding a last line to your .pm file as follows:

```
1;
```

Perl modules must return a true value upon evaluation via `do`, to be loaded successfully via `use` or [`require`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html):

> The file must return true as the last statement to indicate successful execution of any initialization code, so it's customary to end such a file with 1; unless you're sure it'll return true otherwise. But it's better just to put the 1; , in case you add more statements.